How can I start MiniKube as a service on OSX?
I've installed minikube using brew.
brew install minikube

and it works great
❯ minikube start
  minikube v1.33.1 on Darwin 12.0.1
✨  Using the hyperkit driver based on existing profile
  Starting "minikube" primary control-plane node in "minikube" cluster
  Restarting existing hyperkit VM for "minikube" ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.30.0 on Docker 26.0.2 ...
  Configuring bridge CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image registry.k8s.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.7.1
    ▪ Using image docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.7.0
    ▪ Using image docker.io/kubernetesui/metrics-scraper:v1.0.8
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Some dashboard features require the metrics-server addon. To enable all features please run:

        minikube addons enable metrics-server

  Enabled addons: default-storageclass, storage-provisioner, metrics-server, dashboard
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default

But when I reboot the machine, it stops running. I've tried brew services list but it's not listed as a service, so I assume that it's not supported.
I would like it to start before I log in, as a service.
I found this plist online: https://gist.github.com/patdowney/9219219b03a181f22f01fa38d4e5976c
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <!-- needs path to hyperkit and hdiutil -->
      <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>io.k8s.minikube</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/minikube</string>
      <string>start</string>
      <string>--mount</string>
      <string>--mount-string</string>
      <string>/Users:/Users</string>
    </array>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>minikube</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/minikube</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/minikube/stderr.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/minikube/stdout.log</string>
  </dict>
</plist>

I tried to place this in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/io.k8s.minikube.plist
chmod 644 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/io.k8s.minikube.plist

then added launchcontrol load
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/io.k8s.minikube.plist

When I restart the machine, the kube is not running. It seems to be stuck here
* minikube v1.33.1 on darwin
* Using the hyperkit driver based on existing profile
* Starting "minikube" primary control-plane node in "minikube" cluster
* Restarting existing hyperkit VM for "minikube" ...

